# Populate record name automatically

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I want to populate the name of a record by concatenating the values of two other fields, is this possible? I attempted this by using a before insert trigger, but since the system validations(checking if required fields are filled) comes before the before triggers are executed - this didn't work.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Try it by using workflow rule - field update

Comment: Have you marked the name field as required on layout or at the field definition level ? If yes it will fail with workflow as well.

Comment: @Peeyush Workflow field updates too occur later in the order of execution. The system validation rules fire first and put the DML to a halt before it reaches the workflow rule part. Thanks

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty This is the standard name field we are talking about, this is required at all levels.

Comment: But you must enter some test value in name field, and then replace it by W/F  on creation.

Comment: @Peeyush Final option - not at all friendly to end users if you ask me :)

Comment: 1 more work around is that you can make standard name field Auto number and create a custom name field (Formula)

Comment: Name field is only required at the page layouts, but you cannot remove that. If you create the same record using apex, without providing Name, your logic will work. You can consider creating a VF page and insert it using apex.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you want to pre-populate fill `Name` so it doesn't throw any validation error. Workaround is as:

1. Create a Visualforce page similar to this

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Salesforce_Object__c " action="/{!sobjectKeyPrefix}/e?name={!Name_You_Want_To_Pre-populate}&nooverride=1">
   </apex:page>
   ```
2. Replace `Salesforce_Object__c` with your object and `{!Name_You_Want_To_Pre-populate}` with the value you want to be pre-filled.
3. Override the `New` button with the above page.

Customer will not need to enter the name field always.

4. Setup workflow or trigger to replace with actual values.